# How can I decode the input of an ethereum transaction web3js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a web3 contract with a connectAndApprove function

Here is the relevant solidity code.

```
function connectAndApprove(uint32 secret) external returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        approve(dexContract, type(uint256).max);
        emit Approval(owner, dexContract, type(uint256).max);
        return true;
}
```

I have called it with 12345 as the secret and I have the transaction hash. Now I am trying to retrieve the secret. I have been testing on Goerli Network and here is the relevant part of my code using web3js

```
export async function checkTxnDeet(hash) {
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(hash);
    const inputData = transaction.input;
    console.log("data:", inputData);
    const secret = web3.utils.hexToNumberString(inputData);
    const callerAddress = transaction.from;
        const secret2 = web3.utils.hexToAscii(inputData);
    console.log("Secret:", secret);
        console.log("Secret2:", secret2);
    console.log("Caller Address:", callerAddress);

    return { status: true, secret: secret, callerAddress };
}
```

Console log is

```
data: 0xeec1c69f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003039
Transaction was successful
Secret: 463825674249614522252793511716063405085654319944323651944634817017162991046510413623353
Secret2: îÁÆŸ09
Caller Address: (Correct Address)
```

How can I compare or decode the secret back to 12345.

Is it possible to test on Goerli?

I tried multiple things including

```
const decodedSecret = web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(ABI, inputData)
```

It also didn't work

Comment: Will `secret` always be a `uint32` number?

Answer (score 0):

The first 10 characters (4 bytes) of your inputData is the method signature. You need to chop that off and then decode the rest, like this:

```
const methSig = inputData.slice(0, 10);
const secret = contract.methods[methSig].decode(inputData);
const decodedSecret = web3.utils.hexToNumberString(secret);
```